# Issues with quagga and zebra in virtual machine

Tags: linux, debian, quagga

I'm trying to use quagga and zebra in a virtual machine with debian. I installed and configured quagga,  the deamon file and configured the zebra.conf file. When I try to start quagga (service quagga restart) I get the following message:

```
Loading capability module if not yet done.
Starting Quagga deamons (prio:10): zebra/usr/lib/quagga/zebra: option requires an argument -- 'A'
Try 'zebra -- help' for more information
```

and if I try zebra --help the order zebra is not found.

I'm new doing this thing so maybe it's a silly mistake.

Do you know what is happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the OP:

> I solve it by editing the file debian.conf in /etc/quagga. I had in that file: zebra_options= "--daemon -A" and I changed it to zebra_options= "--daemon"